# Is environment configured incorrectly inside VSCode C++ debug session on OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code

I have a programming language I'm fiddling with and it calls clang to link the bitcode file it emits. (Perhaps there is a better way to do this all together?) I've been using Visual Studio Code to debug it and it has mostly worked great.

I recently upgraded llvm. At that point, builtin osx clang was complaining about not recognizing a bitcode construct. So I installed clang part of llvm with brew. This looks to work for the compiler but fails to call the linker.

When I run a debug session I get this in the debug window:

```
clang-6.0: error: unable to execute command: Executable \"ld\" doesn't exist!
```

However, if I run from the embedded terminal it works fine.

It seems like clang is trying to explicitly expand the location of ld rather than using builtin path resolution. Something in VSCode's C++ debugger launched environment is causing issues with it.

Some supporting bits of diagnosis (trying to keep this a bit short for now...).

When run from the debugger:

```
whereis ld works and emits...
/usr/bin/ld

env emits what looks like a wrapped environment...
PWD=/Users/<snipped>
SHLVL=1
_=/usr/bin/env

echo $PATH emits...
/usr/gnu/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:.

And clang tries to link it runs "ld" and says...
clang-6.0: error: unable to execute command: Executable "ld" doesn't exist!
```

When run from the embedded terminal on the other hand:

```
whereis ld works and emits...
/usr/bin/ld

env emits...
a metric ton of stuff including
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin

echo $PATH emits...
/usr/gnu/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:.

And clang tries to run "/usr/bin/ld" which works fine.
```

I realize this may be a clang ld lookup bug (not correctly expanding _=/usr/bin/env??). Unfortunately A) I don't know very much about OSX environment expansion B) if VSCode C++ debugger is using some sort of standard OSX environment jujitsu or not C) not sure how to debug clang run from within an existing VSCode debugger session D) don't know how to emulate the VSCode debugger environment setup to get started unravelling the ball of yarn.

I think I've upgraded OSX/XCode that I'm now unblocked (using the builtin clang compiler from within the VSCode debugger works again). I figured I'd raise this anyway in case I can get a problem fixed or at least learn something.

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Thanks,
Adrian

Comment: `\"ld\"` looks very wrong. It should be `ld`, not `"ld"`, and definitely not `\"ld\"`.

Comment: For whatever reason VSCode's debug output is escaped (it's effectively "ld"). Output from both are escaped similarly. I've adjusted the text. Sorry for the confusion.